# Java Scanner.nextLine() mistakenly parses unicode (emoji) as a new line

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Easiest demonstrated with an example:

```
    String test = "salut ð\u009F\u0098\u0085 test";
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(test);
    System.out.println("1:" + scan.nextLine());
    System.out.println("2:" + scan.nextLine());
```

This was a string in user input so unfortunately I'm not 100% sure what that unicode is, but if I recall correctly, it was an emoji (I saw the message when it was sent).

The output is:

```
    1:salut ð
    2: test
```

My expected output is just 1 line (i.e. the example code should give a `NoSuchElementException` because the second `nextLine()` should fail.). Why is it parsing as two lines? What is a potential workaround?

When I open the file in a text editor it correctly does not treat that unicode as a new line.

Comment: A bit more research has yielded `BufferedReader` as a solution, because apparently `Scanner` treats `\u0085` as a new line token. Still curious about the reason they differ, though.

Comment: `u0085` has the unicode name `NEXT LINE`...

Comment: But is there a reason `BufferedReader` and text editors like Sublime Text don't parse it as an actual new line, while `Scanner` does? It's unclear to me why `Scanner.nextLine()` and `BufferedReader.lines()` can read different results, I always thought they were effectively the same.

Comment: My guess is that `Scanner` is designed to be more "unicode friendly" and matches all kinds of line separators there are, whereas `BufferredReader` and your text editor only recognises the common ones like CR/LF.

Comment: Why are you using 3 unicode characters, instead of 1?

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto This was a logged event from user input. Essentially I was trying to parse the logs, and got this error because it skipped a line and became malformed. I'm 95% sure that the original input was an emoji, i.e. `salut <emoji here> test`. Not sure if emojis are typically represented as 3 unicode chars though (I believe they're typically 2?), perhaps something went wrong in my logging.

Comment: @rococo I believe you tried to write the 3 bytes of a (UTF-8 encoded) Unicode character, but what you wrote is 3 separate Unicode characters, one of which is the `NEL`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is it parsing as two lines?

Although this is an uncommon codepoint, the unicode name of U+0085 *is* NEXT LINE [NEL], I guess it *could* be considered a new line character.

> But is there a reason `BufferedReader` and text editors like Sublime Text don't parse it as an actual new line, while `Scanner` does?

If you look at the respective documentations of `Scanner` and `BufferedReader`:

[`Scanner.nextLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--):

> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any **line separator** at the end. The position is set to the beginning of the next line.
>
> Since this method continues to search through the input looking for a **line separator**...

[`BufferedReader.readLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--):

> Reads a line of text. **A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.**

`Scanner.nextLine` just says "line separator" a very vague term (it certainly doesn't refer to the Unicode category "Line Separators", which only has one codepoint), whereas the `BufferedReader.readLine` documentation states exactly what a line is.

Considering how `Scanner` also handles localised number formats and stuff, my guess is that it is designed to be a "smarter" class than `BufferedReader`.

Looking at the source code of my version of the JDK, `Scanner` considers the following strings "line separators":

- `\r\n`
- `\n`
- `\r`
- `\u2028`
- `\u2029`
- `\u0085`

[The reason why `\u0085` is considered a new line character is apparently related to XML parsing.](https://www.w3.org/TR/newline)